# How to iterate over command line arguments in the shell?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a problem in executing the below program. I need to read the input from the command line and print them as the output. 
The number of command line arguments will vary for each run. Please help.

```
for ((c = 1 ; c <= $# ; c++))
  do
   echo "I got you"
   echo $($c)
  done
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use

```
 #!/bin/sh
 printf 'Number of args: %d\n' $#
 printf 'Args are:\n'
 printf '<%s>\n' "$@"
```

Works in shell functions as well. If you need to iterate,

```
 for arg in "$@"; do
    something with $arg
 done
```

Comment: Or just use `for arg; do` …  That `in "$@"` is the default.

Answer (score 1):

Jens gives you the correct answer. Your approach can work, using [variable indirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
set -- a b c d e

for (( c = 1; c <= $#; c++ )); do
    echo "\$$c = ${!c}"
done
```

```
$1 = a
$2 = b
$3 = c
$4 = d
$5 = e
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple bash script, myscript output looks like this
./cmdArgs.sh num1 num2 num3 num4
I got you
num1
I got you
num2
I got you
num3
I got you
num4

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ $# != 0 ]
do
echo "I got you"
echo "$1"
shift
done
```